# Excluding entries form a variable?

Tags: php, variables

I have this code that i use for a navigation bar:

```
<?php  
$url = 'snip';  
foreach (glob("pages/*") as $path1) {  
  $file1 = basename($path1);  
  $file2 = end(explode('_', $file1));  
  echo "<div class=\"navbutton\"><a style=\"color:#333333;\" href='{$url}index.php?page={$file1}'>$file2</a></div>";
}
?>
```

My folder looks like:

```
pages/
   1_Home  
   2_About  
   404
```

I do not want it to include the file "404", is there a way i can remove it from the variable? Unset doesnt work for some reason.

Comment: How about using `glob('pages/*_*)'`?

Comment: How would i use it, and what would it do? :I

Comment: Use it in place of your existing `glob('pages/*')`.  The `*_*` will only match files that have a `_` in them, hence not match the 404.

Comment: Sorry, i see what it does now. I wasnt thinking clear. I can see what you mean, that's pretty smart. Thanks a lot! Mind posting it as answer so i can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file glob `pages/*` of course matches *all files* in the `pages` directory.  Since everything except the `404` page contains an underscore in the filename, the simplest solution to drop in place is a slightly smarter file glob which only matches those having an underscore, like:

```
 pages/*_*
```

So:

```
foreach (glob("pages/*_*") as $path1) {  
   // Everything else is the same
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was a pretty innovative idea :)